# can i get ip address for free account on heroku

Tags: heroku, socket.io, web-hosting

I want to deploy chat app made in **socket.io** on heroku's **FREE ACCOUNT**

It works fine with **local ip - 127.0.0.1**.

It works fine with **Static Ip - .....**.

but now i want to deploy app on **FREE ACCOUNT** made on heroku

heroku gave me

> url : https://pure-savannah-3208.herokuapp.com/

And in Socket.io i want to put ip address here

```
    var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.0.102');/*How will i get ip address*/
    $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
```

Does heroku provides ip address for free account

or

is there any other way to use this scenario.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket.io accepts domain names, not just IP addresses.

You don't need to do anything.

Comment: I used It like this and it worked `var socket = io.connect('https://pure-savannah-3208.herokuapp.com');`